# Static BottomNavigation inside CoordinatorLayout but not as direct child

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have top level container with `CoordinatorLayout` and `Toolbar` that hides when scolling, this container contain fragments.

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.screens.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

One of my fragments contain `RecycleView` and `BottomNavigation`

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:pp="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <BottomNavigation />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem that the `BottomNavigation` scrolls with the content, when the app start the `BottomNavigation` almost invisible, and when I scroll down the `BottomNavigation` became visible and vise versa, I need it to be static without scroll behavior, is there any configuration for that?

I guess the problem because `BottomNavigation` is not direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` but is there workaround?

Demo project(ignore slideshow and gallery):

https://github.com/pavelpoley/CoordinatorLayoutQuestion

Comment: I'm offering help but you need to create demo project on Github. Thanks

Comment: @HarisDautović added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from your `content_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** After demo project has been updated with a more complex hierarchy provided solution above didn't work as expected.

I did a lot of research and couldn't find any clean solution to have `BottomNavigationView` inside `CoordinatorLayout` but not as a direct child.

The only solution was to move `BottomNavigationView` inside  `CoordinatorLayout` as a child and then change its visibility based on `androidx.navigation.NavController` destination.

**Source code:** https://github.com/dautovicharis/CoordinatorLayoutQuestion/commits/master

[image]

Comment: hm, it actually works for demo project, but not for the original, when I remove behavior from `content_main` the toolbar disappears at all, maybe because in my original app the nesting is more deep

Comment: Can you update demo project to be the same structure as original app?

Comment: updated, but still some difference , `content_main` without behavior make the toolbar gone in the original project, and kind of overlap in the demo

Comment: @PavelPoley Maybe in your original project you are using different app theme. Also, maybe programatically you are doing something that is resulting in different toolbar behaviour. If you update demo project with new setup please let me know so I can check again.

Comment: Updated to same behavior as in original project, but something strange there `appBarLayout` with `elevetion 0` and `contant_main` with `background color` make the toolbar invisible, if you remove elevation and background the toolbar overlap the content

Comment: @PavelPoley One of solutions is to move BottomNavigationView from fragment to app_bar_main.xml.  I think this standard approach how it's usually done.
Here is code: https://github.com/dautovicharis/CoordinatorLayoutQuestion/commits/master

Comment: I thought about this solution, but this BottomNavigationView used only in 2 fragments out of 20, and it kind of weird in sense of responsibility to move it up in the hierarchy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226409/discussion-between-haris-dautovic-and-pavel-poley).

Comment: @PavelPoley I have added additional informations in discussion chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a couple of changes

- Add `exitUntilCollapsed` flag to the `Toolbar`

  `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"`
- Remove the `app:layout_behavior` from the `NestedScrollView`, and add it to root `ConstraintLayout`

By applying those, the layouts will be:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.screens.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And fragment:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:pp="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <BottomNavigation />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help, I have attached demo project

Comment: @PavelPoley please let me check it